# How Disable connecting to database on spring boot startup

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

While starting my Spring Boot app, I can see from the logs that it's connecting to the GCP cloud instance database on startup:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [**] via SSL socket.
c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [**] via SSL socket.
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

How can I delay the establishing of the connection until a request that needs the database is made?

Comment: You can try [that](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-lazy-initialization), but for database connexion it shouldn't work. You can deep dive into spring boot, deactivate the autoloader of database connection and manage it manually. It's boring, touchy, and hard to recommend. So, why do you have this requirement?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere To speed up Spring Boot startup time.

Comment: I switched from Java Spring Boot to Golang for this exact same reason. But, by discussion with Google Developer Advocate, they proposed me different way to optimise the startup time. [APPCDS](https://medium.com/@toparvion/appcds-for-spring-boot-applications-first-contact-6216db6a4194) is one solution. GraalVM is more and more stable and reliable with Spring Boot and can be also a solution. In addition, Spring Boot start faster when you have 3 CPUs, try to change your platform setting also.